# Nginx site not getting picked up

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

My new site is not getting picked up. I've created `appycontrol.staging`:

```
upstream appycontrol_staging {
  server unix:///var/www/appycontrol.staging/shared/sockets/puma.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name control-staging.somedomain.com;
    root /var/www/appycontrol.staging/current/public;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://appycontrol_staging;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

I've added a symbolic link in the `sites-enabled` directory:

```
[Staging] deploy@localhost:~$ ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Nov  3  2015 appyengine.staging -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/appyengine.staging
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Jul  7 06:03 appycontrol.staging -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/appycontrol.staging
```

And I've restarted nginx:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

But control-staging.somedomain.com gets picked up by the `appyengine.staging` site instead.

What am I missing?

Comment: Providing log data may help you in getting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the nginx error log, I had this:

```
2016/07/11 03:53:40 [emerg] 10446#0: a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/appyengine.staging:6
```

So I changed line 6 to `listen 80` and restarted nginx. Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably used a wild card domain in the other config file, or starting nginx fails for some reason.

Also `///var/` should just be `/var/`.

Comment: I didn't have a wild card and I didn't get any error when restarting nginx. Although there was an error in the error log.